# Tab bar appearance highlighting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, interface-builder

Need to tweak the appearance of this tab bar. I created one just like this and it went well. But when you tap on one of the tab buttons it turns dim till you let it go. How do I get rid of this? Also when you tap on one of the buttons that is already selected, it turns to unselected stated then back to selected when you let off. How do I make it so that when you tap on a tab button that's already selected there's no visual feedback?

http://www.rumexit.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/

Comment: What is "this tab bar"? Can you provide a code sample or screenshot?

Comment: I don't think you really have a tabbar. Maybe a toolbar with buttons? By default, a tabbar does not behave as you described.

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't tested the code, but if it doesn't work it should tell you everything you need to know to find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. When you tap on a tab button that's already selected there's no visual feedback.

The tab bar pretty much is what it is. If you want it to look or behave differently you're going to have to implement your own subviews.

**EDIT:** It would be good if you would have provide that link directly. Your question isn't about tab bars, but how to disable highlighting on `UIButton`.

The first hit on Google suggests:

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

If that doesn't work for you I'm sure one of the other suggestions will.

Comment: The tab bar's tabs each have two states; selected and not selected. When a tab is in the selected state and you click on it while already in that state, it momentarily goes to the not selected state. So it's showing an image of deselection when nothing is supposed to happen.

Comment: @supermonkey The default tab bar doesn't do that. You're obviously doing something wrong, but without code it's really hard to tell you what.